# How would you implement a destructor for a BST in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

How would you implement a destructor for a BST in C++? I'm making a separate function that will be called in the destructor. It's also a template BST.

It's for a class so no code please. Just the logic or some pseudo code thanks!

Comment: See CComBSTR https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx

Comment: Why can't the function take any parameters? That seems like a pretty unusual restriction.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer not to write any destructors at all.

Just make sure that the BST class stores a unique_ptr to the root node, and each node stores unique_ptr-s to its children. Then the whole tree would be destructed automatically when the BST object is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have seen it done is by using some recursive function that goes all the way down to the leaves, delete the children and nulling the pointers as it moves back up to the root.

```
function recursiveRelease(root)
if root!= null
  if (leftchild)
    recursiveRelease(leftchild)
    remove leftchild from tree
    make pointer to leftchild = nullptr
  if (rightchild)
    recursiveRelease(rightchild)
    remove rightchild from tree
    make pointer to rightchild = nullptr
```

After that the root gets destroyed; hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is an O(n)-time, O(1)-space algorithm for deleting all the nodes in a BST that doesn't require any recursion. The idea is the following:

- If the root has no left child, cache a pointer to the tree's right child, delete the root node, then continue deleting the tree that used to be the right subtree.
- Otherwise, if the root has a left child, perform a [tree rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation) to rotate the left child over the root.

This process eventually deletes all the nodes in the tree, requires no recursion, and requires only constant extra space.

That said... it is really odd that you can't have your helper function have parameters. That sounds like a pretty arbitrary restriction. You may want to ask why exactly that's the case.

Comment: Oh, very neat. Thanks for writing this answer.